# Storing log files on cloud

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, cloud-storage

I have developed a desktop application that will be used without my presence. Therefore, my program may register different events - input, executed operations, working time. Is it possible to modify app for sending logs to any cloud for remote viewing reports?

I have accounts on Wuala and Google Drive, but not a problem to register somewhere else (DropBox? SkyDrive? I don't know what cloud will be easier for work in this situation).

Or you can suggest another, more elegant, solution.

I am using C#, .Net 2.0. Logs are simple .txt files.

Comment: can't you just access the logs via ftp or something on that machine? sending logs across the internets to a dropbox or whatever can be terribly insecure

Comment: Not clear what kind of advise you are looking for: how to upload file for a given service/FTP, what service to use to store files, kind of legal issues you are getting into by silently uploading users' data or something else?

Comment: @ChristianWestman my logs doesn't contains valuable info for third parties :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov which cloud is easier to work and how to send files on it using c#